# $\mathrm{LP}$ formulation for $\mathrm{k}$-$\operatorname{opt}$ moves

Tags: algorithms, linear-programming, combinatorial-optimization, heuristics, traveling-salesman-problem

$\mathrm{k}$-$\operatorname{opt}$ moves are an idea to improve non-optimal Hamilton cycles in weighted symmetric graphs by exchanging $\mathrm{k}$ tour-edges with $\mathrm{k}$ edges that do not belong to the tour, have smaller weightsum and yield a different tour when exchanged with the selected tour-edges; cf e.g [General k-opt submoves for the Lin–Kernighan TSP heuristic](http://mpc.zib.de/archive/2009/3/Helsgaun2009_Article_GeneralK-optSubmovesForTheLinK.pdf).

My impression is that no polynomial size $\mathrm{LP}$-formulations for finding $\mathrm{k}$-$\operatorname{opt}$ moves are available and that in implementations $\mathrm{k}$ is limited to very small fixed values, e.g. $5$.

> **Question:**
>
> is my impression right that no polynomial size $\mathrm{LP}$-formulations for $\mathrm{k}$-$\operatorname{opt}$ moves are known, not even for fixed $\mathrm{k}$, resp. which such formulations are known and what can be said about their integrality gap?

It appears to me that candidate edge-sets whose exchange results in a cycle cover of lower weight, that *may* be a tour, can be found by polynomial size $\mathrm{LP}$'s and that there are polynomial size $\mathrm{ILP}$-formulations that reliably identify edge-sets whose exchange *yields* a shorter tour but whose $\mathrm{LP}$ relaxation may have an integrality gap.

Answer (score 0):

For a simplified formulation of necessary constraints for $\mathrm{k}$ moves it is assumed that the vertices have been relabeled so that $0,\,\dots,\,n-1$ reflects the order in which they are encountered when the tour is traveled.

Then three necessary conditions that can be identified are

- *degree conservation* constraints:
  for every vertex the number of adjacent in-edges must be equal to the number of adjacent out-edges
- *what comes in must go out* constraints:
  for every vertex $i$ the sum of ingoing edges of its neighbors $i-1$ and $i+1$ must not be smaller than the number of $i$'s ingoing edges.
- *subtour elimination* constraints:
  if $\mathrm{X}$ is graph induced by the union of tour-edges and in-edges, then no in-edges $f_{ij}$ must exist such that $\mathrm{X}\setminus\lbrace i,\,j\rbrace$ is disconnected because otherwise every exchange set that contains $f_{ij}$ would result in a disconnected cycle cover.

The corresponding linear program can then be formulated as

\begin{align*}
\text{min} \quad
\tau^\prime x\ +\ \sigma^\prime y & \\
\text{s.t.} \quad
x_{i-1,i}+x_{i,i+1}&=\sum\limits_{2\le\left|j-i\right|}y_{ij} \\
\sum\limits_j y_{ij} &\le \sum\limits_j y_{i-1,j}+\sum\limits_j y_{i+1,j}\\
y_{ij} &\le\sum\limits_{i\lt u\lt j\lt v}y_{uv}\quad+\sum\limits_{u\lt i\lt v\lt j}y_{uv}\\
x_{i,i+1},x_{n-1,0}\,,\, y_{ij} &\in\lbrace 0,1\rbrace
\end{align*}

where $\tau$ is the vector of tour-edge weights and $\sigma$ the vector of non-tour edge weights; additons and subtraction of indices corresponding to vertex labels are to be understood modulo $n$

The *degree conservation* constraints are analogous to the *flow conservation* constraints and would thus yield an integral solution if the *subtour elimination* constraints were not part of the above linear program.
Most likely the *subtour elimation* constraints will lead to non-integral solutions.

A further thought is as to whether utilizing MTZ constraints for subtour elimination would be worthwile to investigate.